# Average Rows by Category Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I've got a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    year    geo_name            adult_obesity   some_college    STATE_ABBR
0   2015    Autauga County, AL  0.313           NaN             AL
1   2016    Autauga County, AL  0.309           0.565           AL
2   2017    Autauga County, AL  0.341           0.597           AL
3   2013    Baldwin County, AL  NaN             NaN             AL
4   2014    Baldwin County, AL  NaN             NaN             AL
5   2015    Baldwin County, AL  0.250           0.625           AL
6   2016    Baldwin County, AL  0.267           0.623           AL
7   2017    Baldwin County, AL  0.274           0.629           AL
8   2015    Barbour County, AL  0.384           0.423           AL
9   2016    Barbour County, AL  0.408           0.434           AL
```

I want to condense all these county data to state data and take the average per state per year.

So I want a new dataset with an unique state and year, and in there the average of the original other rows with the same state and year (`adult_obesety`, `some_college`).

Any way to easily do that with pandas?

Comment: `KeyError: ' STATE_ABBR'`

Comment: Sorry, it was typo, I correct it.

Comment: Uh this puts rows inside a year row. Would it be possible to have a one dimentional dataframe where the year is another row?

Comment: Not sure if understand, can you add desired output?

Comment: Maybe need `df.groupby(['year','STATE_ABBR'], as_index=False).mean()`

Comment: Many thanks, it works! If you want you could post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate `mean`:

```
df = df.groupby(['year','STATE_ABBR'], as_index=False).mean()
print (df)
   year STATE_ABBR  adult_obesity  some_college
0  2013         AL            NaN           NaN
1  2014         AL            NaN           NaN
2  2015         AL       0.315667      0.524000
3  2016         AL       0.328000      0.540667
4  2017         AL       0.307500      0.613000
```