# How do I aggregate rows with similar strings values as new rows in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is a DataFrame I created using Pandas...

```
╔════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║        Column A        ║ Column B ║
╠════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ /                      ║ 5.34     ║
║ new-shirts             ║ 6.78     ║
║ new-pants              ║ 10.11    ║
║ used-hats              ║ 1.56     ║
║ used-shirts            ║ 3.78     ║
║ brand-new-watches/gold ║ 4.21     ║
║ customer-service       ║ 0.29     ║
║ holiday-blowout-sale   ║ 12.45    ║
║ used-pants/corduroy    ║ 2.98     ║
║ special-discounts      ║ 6.99     ║
║ contact-us             ║ 1.67     ║
╚════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

I want to aggregate rows with similar strings as new rows in "Column A" ("Home" would be "/", anything with "new" in it would become "New", anything with "used" in it would become "Used", anything with "service" in it would become "Service" and everything else would get pushed to "Other") and find the average of those values in "Column B" like shown below. How would I do that using Python and Pandas?

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║ Column A ║ Column B ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣
║ Home     ║ 5.34     ║
║ New      ║ 7.03     ║
║ Used     ║ 2.77     ║
║ Service  ║ 0.29     ║
║ Other    ║ 7.04     ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

In addition is it also possible to combine certain pages like "customer-service" and "contact-us" into the new row "Service" without "contact-us" also being counted towards "Other"?

Thank you!

EDIT:

@Erfan - Your solution worked great for how the initial DataFrame was presented, but I realized it's missing relevant data. How would your solution change if it looked like this instead and I was trying to achieve the same result?

```
╔═════════════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║            Column A             ║ Column B ║
╠═════════════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ /                               ║ 5.34     ║
║ /new-shirts/                    ║ 6.78     ║
║ /new-pants/                     ║ 10.11    ║
║ /used-hats/                     ║ 1.56     ║
║ /used-shirts/                   ║ 3.78     ║
║ /brand-new-watches/gold/        ║ 4.21     ║
║ /customer-service/              ║ 0.29     ║
║ /holiday-blowout-sale/december/ ║ 12.45    ║
║ /used-pants/corduroy/           ║ 2.98     ║
║ /special-discounts/             ║ 6.99     ║
║ /contact-us/                    ║ 1.67     ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: I suggest checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47569869/average-rows-by-category-pandas

Comment: I think you should use an intermediate column that connects the strings in your first example with the categories from your second example, and then use that as an aggregator. In SQL this is called a 'join'; I don't know what pandas calls it.

Comment: _How would I do that using Python and Pandas?_ Have you actually done anything? Stack Overflow is not the place to have others do all your work for you.

Answer (score -1):

We can define your words you want to categorize by, then use `Series.str.extract` to extract these categories from your strings.

Then we use `GroupBy.sum` to get the sum per category:

```
words = ['/', 'New', 'Used', 'Service']

cats = (
    df['Column A'].str.extract('((?i)'+'|'.join(words)+')')
                  .fillna('other')[0]
                  .str.capitalize()
                  .str.replace('/', 'Home')
)

df = df.groupby(cats, sort=False)['Column B'].mean().rename_axis('Column A', axis=0).reset_index()
```

```
  Column A  Column B
0     Home  5.340000
1      New  7.033333
2     Used  2.773333
3  Service  0.290000
4    Other  7.036667
```

Comment: Thank you for the incredible response! This works great! My only issue is that the initial table or DataFrame I gave you was a terrible example that's missing relevant data. I've added a new table/DataFrame in an edit to my original post. Based on that DataFrame how would your solution change?